# How to find the parent id's of an h1 tag array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have something like this in my HTML:

```
<div id="div0"></div>
<div id="div1"><h1>h1(0)</h1></div>
<div id="div2"><h1>h1(1)</h1></div>
<div id="div3"><h1 class="center">h1(2)</h1></div>
<div id="div4"><h1>h1(3)</h1><h1>h1(4)</h1></div>
```

My Javascript:

```
var tags=document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
console.log(tags) =
  HTMLCollection[h1,h1,h1.center,h1,h1]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get the id of the parent of, say, tags[2], which would be "div3".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
tags[2].parentNode.id;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.parentNode

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.parentElement

Comment: "id of the parent of, say, tags[2]" + Yoda + Javascript = `tags[2].parentNode.id`

Answer (score 2):

You can try:-

```
tags[2].parentElement.id
```

[parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.parentElement)

or

```
tags[2].parentNode.id
```

[parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.parentNode)

Both are almost similar, one difference is when a the Node's parentNode is not an element. If so, parentElement will be null. eg;- if you are looking at the `HTML` element, parentNode will return you `documentElement` whereas parentElement will return null.

Small fiddle to demonstrate the main difference [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gyhYf/)